# jQuery scroll to a specific index number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll

I want to scroll to a specific index number in a list of child elements.

What is the simplest and effective way to do this.

The only restrictions are where the index is a number from 0 to n-1. And I retrieve index from $(this).index(); when the item was clicked and saved to scroll again at some other point in time like in a memory game.

I was thinking something like this but more eloquent:

```
   $("child:nth-child(" + index + ")").scroll();

<parent>
 <child/>
 <child/>
 <child/>
...
 <child/> <!-- nth child-->
</parent>
```

Comment: You could simulate the clicking of an anchor

Comment: Why not just `$.scrollTop($(this).offset().top);`

Comment: It doesn't work on all mobile devices running jQuery mobile 1.3.2.  But I'll give it a try.  At least for some mobile devices.  But desktop browsers it does work.

Comment: Never mind, its actually working ;)

Comment: Never mind again.  I was in debug mode but it doesn't work for my case specific iphone devices in 1.3.2. darn.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old one. Maybe this answer will help someone.

```
let index = 3; // find index for the li tag
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('ul#list li');
rows[index].scrollIntoView({
   behavior: 'smooth',
   block: 'start'
});
```